# can't get my program to return to main loop

Tags: python

I can't get the bottom part of this code to work. I want the user to be able to type "back" and return to the main menu. 
Is there anyone that can help, and that can explain why it wont work the way I have done it here?

I have tried more versions of the same thing, tried using "if rf.read() == "back"" too, but I just can't figgure it out and it's annoying me that it wont work so that the user can return. The way it is now, if they don't know the file name or want to go back and check they would just get stuck
        import os, sys

```
def loop():
    while True:
        choice = menuchoice()
        choiceexec(choice)


def menuchoice():
    showmenu()
    while True:
        validchoices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        try:
            choice = int(input("What would you like to do? "))

            if choice not in validchoices:
                print(repr(choice) + "Invalid menu choice")

            if choice in validchoices:
                return choice

        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid choice. Try again!")

def showmenu():
    print("1 - Show current directory path")
    print("2 - Show file names in current directory")
    print("3 - Show all directories and files in current path")
    print("4 - Enter new directory path")
    print("5 - Read a .txt file in current directory")
    print("6 - Write in a .txt file in current directory")
    return

def choiceexec(x):
    if x == 1:
        showdirectory()
    if x == 2:
        filesindir()
    if x == 3:
        allinfo()
    if x == 4:
        newpath()
    if x == 5:
        opentxtfile()
    if x == 6:
        writetxtfile()
    if x == 7:
        exit()




#def:
def showdirectory():
    print(os.getcwd())
    print("\n")

def filesindir():
    print(os.listdir())
    print("\n")

def allinfo():
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
        print("Current path: ", dirpath)
        print("Directories: ", dirnames)
        print("Files: ", filenames)
        print("\n")



def newpath():
    pathinput = input("Enter new directory path: ")
    os.chdir(pathinput)
    print("Current path is now:", pathinput)
    print("\n")
    return


def opentxtfile():

    openfile = input("Enter the .txt file name: ")
    with open(openfile, 'r') as f:
        f_content = f.read()
        print(f_content)
        print("\n")
        f.close()

def writetxtfile():

    try:
        openfile = input("Enter the .txt file name, or type 'back' to go back to menu: ")
        with open(openfile, 'r') as rf:
            f_content = rf.read()
            print("Current file text:",f_content)
            print("\n")
        writeinput  = input("What would you like to write?")
        with open(openfile, 'a') as wf:
            wf.write(" " + writeinput)
            wf.close()
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        writetxtfile()
    else:                               #### not working
        if openfile == "back":
            return


def exit():
    sys.exit()

loop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to change `writetxtfile()` to:

```
def writetxtfile():
    try:
        openfile = input("Enter the .txt file name, or type 'back' to go back to menu: ")
        if openfile == "back":
            return
        else:
            with open(openfile, 'r') as rf:
                f_content = rf.read()
                print("Current file text:",f_content)
                print("\n")
            writeinput  = input("What would you like to write?")
            with open(openfile, 'a') as wf:
                wf.write(" " + writeinput)
                wf.close()
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        writetxtfile()
```